# Receive 1004 error when launch code

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to execute some little program, and I have 1004 error
Here is my code

```
Sub program2()
    With Worksheets("Test")
        .Range("a1").Value = "Test"
        .Range("b1") = "Test"
        .Cells(2, 2) = "Test"
        .Range("b2").Font.ColorIndex = 3
    End With
    With Range("a1:b1").Font = 9
        .Bold = True
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 16
        .ColorIndex = 5
    End With
End Sub
```

Could anyone tell me please, whats wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
With Range("a1:b1").Font
    '.Size = 9   ' 9 or 16; not both
    .Bold = True
    .Name = "Arial"
    .Size = 16
    .ColorIndex = 5
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you're looking for:

```
Sub program2()
    With Worksheets("Test")
        .Range("a1").Value = "Test"
        .Range("b1") = "Test"
        .Cells(2, 2) = "Test"
        .Range("b2").Font.ColorIndex = 3
    End With
    With Range("a1:b1").Font
        .Bold = True
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 16
        .ColorIndex = 5
    End With
End Sub
```